# I want to have pictures with javascript in diffierent dropdowns in my site

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to have my site to have different dropdowns with pictures included, just like how it works at: reddit.com/r/cats. I've tried searching on the internet everywhere and I made it work but I don't know how to make it so that every dropdown shows a different picture. For reference look at my site: P1zzah.github.io

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover,
.dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #515151;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 75px;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 15px
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="Pizza Icon.png" type="image/x-icon">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <title>Pizzah - Top 10</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="footer">Gemaakt in 2017 in opdracht van het ds. Pierson College - Alle rechten voorbehouden</div>
  <img id="banner" src="Pizza Banner.jpg" alt="Pizza banner">
  <h1 id="Titel">Top 10</h1>
  <br>
  <div style="width:100%">
    <div style="float:left; height:30px;">
      <h2> 10. <a href="http://images.meredith.com/content/dam/bhg/Images/recipe/37/R082465.jpg.rendition.largest.jpg"> Pizza margherita </a> </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="dropdown" style="float:right">
        <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn"></button>
        <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
          <img src="http://images.meredith.com/content/dam/bhg/Images/recipe/37/R082465.jpg.rendition.largest.jpg">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="width:100%">
      <div style="float:left; height:40px;">
        <h2> 9.<a href="http://oetker-cdn-prod.azureedge.net/image/231758/0x0/0/big-americans-supreme.png"> American supreme </a> </h2>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn"></button>
        <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content" style="float:right width: 30px; ">
          <img src="http://images.meredith.com/content/dam/bhg/Images/recipe/37/R082465.jpg.rendition.largest.jpg">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h2> 8. <a href="http://www.pizzamaken.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Pizza-bolognese.jpg">
            Pizza bolognese </a>
    </h2>
    <h2> 7. <a href="https://i.warosu.org/data/ck/img/0082/72/1479057900804.png"> Big american bbq chicken </a> </h2>
    <h2> 6. <a href="http://www.lekkerenanders.nl/images/2000x1194/donerpizza.jpg"> Pizza döner van de Maestro </a></h2>
    <h2> 5. <a href="http://www.multivu.com/assets/52225/photos/Pizza-Hut-Pan-Supreme-10-dollar-Re-Launch-original.jpg?1316219584">Pizza hut chicken supreme </a></h2>
    <h2> 4.
      <a href="https://bestellen.dominos.nl/ManagedAssets/OLO/iPad/All/Product/NL/PBMG/PBMG_ProductImage_Large_nl_Default_20130919.png">Domino's bbq mixed grill </a></h2>
    <h2> 3. <a href="http://cdn.schwans.com/media/images/products/56720-1-1540.jpg ">Pepperoni pizza </a></h2>
    <h2> 2. <a href="https://az809444.vo.msecnd.net/image/3481323/0x0/0/big-americans-2017-texasv1png.png "> Big american texas </a></h2>
    <h2>Voor de nummer 1 klik hier!</h2>
    <ul>
      <li style="float:left "><img id="LogoImage " src="Pizza Logo.png "></li>
      <li style="float:left ">
        <h1 id="Logo ">PIZZAH</h1>
      </li>
      <li><a href="overons.html ">OVER ONS</a></li>
      <li><a class="active " href="top10.html ">TOP 10</a></li>
      <li><a href="funfacts.html ">FUN FACTS</a></li>
      <li><a href="ingredienten.html ">INGREDIËNTEN</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.html ">HOME</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: can you provide some code and maybe a more specific example

Comment: Edited it to include code

Answer (score 0):

You can set image and text together like this.

```
<a href="#"><img src="Blabla.jpg">Your Text Here </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You were toggling the class `show` without declaring it in your css

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover,
.dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:100%">
  <div style="float:left; height:30px;">
    <h2> 10. <a href="http://"> Pizza margherita </a> </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <div class="dropdown" style="float:right">
      <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn"></button>
      <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
        <img src="http://images.meredith.com/content/dam/bhg/Images/recipe/37/R082465.jpg.rendition.largest.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: That helped thanks. Another question I've got is: I want to do this dropdown for every pizza in my top 10 (so i have to make 10 different blocks which show different pictures when clicked), what do i have to change in order to get them all different pictures, i've tried copying and giving them different classes etc. but that didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: why dont you post the full html and i can help you with the script

Comment: I've posted the full html, As you can see it worked for number 10 and i tried to copy and paste it for number 9, but when clicking the box next to number 9 it opens the box next to number 10 instead of number 9.

Comment: clean your html, u got a big mess and will make it really hard to work on

Answer (score 0):

You still need to work on your html, but this is a general solution

```js
function myFunction(x) {

  document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content")[x].classList.toggle("show");
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover,
.dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:100%">
  <div style="float:left; height:30px;">
    <h2> 10. <a href="http://"> Pizza margherita </a> </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <div class="dropdown" style="float:right">
      <button onclick="myFunction(0)" class="dropbtn"></button>
      <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
        <img src="http://images.meredith.com/content/dam/bhg/Images/recipe/37/R082465.jpg.rendition.largest.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left; height:30px;">
      <h2> 9. <a href="http://"> Pizza 2 </a> </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="dropdown" style="float:right">
        <button onclick="myFunction(1)" class="dropbtn"></button>
        <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
          <img src="http://images.meredith.com/content/dam/bhg/Images/recipe/37/R082465.jpg.rendition.largest.jpg">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```